# go compile error: unknown field in struct literal

Tags: go

I have a go package that has the following struct:

```
package transforms
type MqttConfig struct {
    Qos            byte  
}

type KeyCertPair struct { 
    KeyFile      string 
}
```

In my main.go, I import the package and use both of them liek this:

```
    import ( sdkTransforms "github.com/edgexfoundry/app-functions-sdk-go/pkg/transforms")

    type AWSMQTTConfig struct {
        MQTTConfig  *sdkTransforms.MqttConfig
        KeyCertPair *sdkTransforms.KeyCertPair
    }

    config := AWSMQTTConfig{}

    //FIRST
    pair := &sdkTransforms.KeyCertPair{
            KeyFile:  mqttKey,
    }

    //SECOND
    mqttcfg := &sdkTransforms.MqttConfig{
            Qos:            2,    
    }
```

But only the second usage gives me this compile error:

```
unknown field 'Qos' in struct literal of type transforms.MqttConfig
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that you are pointing to a version of the sdkTransforms package that doesn't have that field for MqttConfig?

Comment: @bserdar Actually the MqttConfig changed recently and a new field was added, but Qos is an old field, should be already there. Is there any check I can make to see what version I am picking? The makefile looks ok.

Comment: check go.mod, see which version it is looking at.

Comment: @bserdar I have cloned the repo and it contains the correct struct, but in the go cache I have the old version. I don't know how to clean the environment but your answer is right. If you answer, I will vote

Comment: In your `AWSMQTTConfig` struct, `MqttConfig` and `KeyCertPair` are NOT embedded. But the error you shared in your question concerns `transforms.MqttConfig`, a different struct. Can you share the structure the error references ?

Comment: @yazgazan sorry for using the wrong term. The problem is that in my environment I have the wrong version, even if I had cloned the correct one

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that you are pointing to a version of the sdkTransforms package that doesn't have that field for MqttConfig. You can do a `go get <module>` to get the latest version and try again.